# Finding illegal links in questions and answers

Tags: discussion

Sometimes we miss them, sometimes they get edited in later. Here's a query to find all instances of the words *mangafox*, *kissanime* and *mangareader*:

https://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/541047

You can edit the query to add more words contained in potentially illegal links.

Forums and discussion pages on the same domains should be ok to leave, but direct links to videos and manga are not.

Comment: With some [small additions](https://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/541033) It covers a few more unwanted providers.

Comment: thanks, I edited and added it to the post

Answer (score 9):

Censuring the mere mention of the site and other like it will most likely get us nowhere. I believe it's fine to mention the site (and similar ones) in name only.

However links to illegal content should be flagged for removal or edited out (if you have the appropriate privilege). Be sure to leave a message to the one that posted it letting him know that the link is not alright on our site.